# Google Webmaster Tools reports URLs blocked by robots.txt on my AVS tube website

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, robots.txt

I added a tube (with AVS script) in Google Webmaster Tools, but the issue is with the *robots.txt* file which is blocking everything.

Here is my AVS tube *robots.txt*:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /siteadmin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /include/
Disallow: /install/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /classes/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /addons/
Disallow: /cron/
Disallow: /contrib/
```

Have to mention that the site is with non-www version. When someone types in the www. version of the site it will be redirected to non-www version.

This is the message from Webmaster Tools:

> Url blocked by *robots.txt*.
>
> Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by *robots.txt*.

Comment: Having just launched a new site I'm having exactly the same problem. Never seen it before. I'm wondering if Webmaster Tools (Search Console) has a cached version of my robots file (initial launch had `Disallow: /*` from when we were testing). I can see the new robots.txt in the testing system... but it is blocking every page, and none of the pages sit in blocked folders.

Comment: Can you upload a copy of your sitemap file as the error being displayed indicates that there is a URL in your sitemap file which is blocked by the robots.txt, Need to see the sitemap.xml file to check what is happening.

Comment: How can I PM you to show you the sitemap?